# slowly animate a simple line

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

My problem is that the line *draw is instantaneous*.

What I want is it to *draw the line very slowly*, almost 3-5 seconds before it finishes at `dy`. For some reason I cannot get the `setTimeout()` to work. I have tried large and small values.

I just have a basic line example but I will expand on this concept to include `x` and `bezier lines` once I can figure how the timeout works.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function myLine(x, y, dx, dy) { //Line constructor
  this.x = x; //start x
  this.y = y; //start y
  this.dx = dx; //end x
  this.dy = dy; //end y
}
var line = new myLine(100, 5, 100, 100); //line object

function drawLine(myLine, context) { //Draw function
    context.moveTo(myLine.x, myLine.y);   
    animate(line, context);
  }
function animate(myLine, context) { //animation function
    if (myLine.y < myLine.dy) {
      myLine.y = myLine.y + 1;
      context.lineTo(myLine.dx, myLine.y);
      context.stroke();
      window.setTimeout(animate(line, context), 1000/60);
    }
}
drawLine(line, context);
```

Comment: can u use jQuery or it has to be done with javaScript only ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually *not* what you want to do: computers don't do things "slowly", especially not in a context that is single-threaded. What you want to do instead is draw *lots* of lines, over and over, where each next line is a little longer than the previous one. That way, it looks like the line is growing, and you get exactly what you want:

```
function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,ratio) {
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  x2 = x1 + ratio * (x2-x1);
  y2 = y1 + ratio * (y2-y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  // And if we intend to start new things after
  // this, and this is part of an outline, 
  // we probably also want a ctx.closePath()
}

function animate(ratio) {
  ratio = ratio || 0;
  drawLine(0,0,300,300,ratio);
  if(ratio<1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      animate(ratio + 0.01);
    });
  }
}

animate();
```

Running code: http://jsbin.com/hanaqahoyu/edit?html,js,output

Also note that we **do not** want to use setTimeout: in order to ensure smooth animation, modern browsers have `requestAnimationFrame`, which is going to trigger *when it makes the most sense for a frame of animation*, which is super handy: we'll use that.

Comment: How is performance between your approach and my approach if I added requestAnimationFrame to mine?

Comment: pretty much the same comparable, although I'd argue that the way you've spread your logic needs a little tightening so you do all your "what to draw, then draw it" logic inside one function. Hence the small rewrite to ratio computation in the jsbin

Comment: very nice, now is there a nice way to animate with the bezierCurveTo? I assume the control points are going to be some type of ratio of x2 and y2?

Comment: Beziers are non-linear: you have to recompute the control points at each iteration by performing curve splitting (http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting) and instead of using a `ratio`, using a control variable `t` to move along the curve.

Comment: Don't forget to use beginPath() before each line.

Comment: beginPath is only necessary if we're also closePath'ing, but yes, good advice

Comment: @K3N also remember that's it's fine to correct minor issues on someone's answer, but an answer is not a post: it's not fine to change their code to do what you would have answered - that's what comments are for and then the answerer can update their answer if necessary. (beginPath is good advice, but in this case absolutely not necessary, which is why I intentionally left it off, and edited the answer to take it out again)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit The meaning is not changed, an error was corrected. Yes, it is necessary as it will slow down the browser. A single line, fine, but I suspect OP is gonna use it for more than that. In any case, future reader may come across this post so a correct usage should be posted.

Comment: all fair points, all points to raise in a comment, not edit someone's answer over. Tell them first, then if they don't edit their answer, swoop in with override super powers =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I *did* tell you first.. ;) It's necessary as each sub-path you add will accumulate. It is not related to closePath (which simply connects last point to first point, either in main path or sub-path).

Comment: It doesn't take many seconds before this becomes sluggish - if you add beginPath in there the problem goes away: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/hr99LcLn/

Comment: speaking of optimizations.........I've made some progess with the Bezier, should I look at matrices? http://jsfiddle.net/Mangopineapples/04gL3pa6/

Comment: that draws the curve as a sequence of lines. That's an option, but another is to use ctx.bezierCurveTo and split the curve "for real", such as in http://jsbin.com/kocugetoqo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

[`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) takes a function reference as its first argument, you've passed in the result of calling `animate()`, which is `undefined`. This won't do much.

A simple fix is an anonymous function.

```
window.setTimeout(function () { animate(line, context); }, 1000/60);
```

The more advanced method is to use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
window.setTimeout(animate.bind(null, line, context), 1000/60);
```

Additionally, since you're working with animations, consider looking into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was confused by the docs because some of them had anonymous calls and others didn't. I should've tried the anonymous function calls first

Comment: I've looked into requestAnimationFrame, but I don't know if I will need it. I'm building an interactive Q/A feature on a website and this animation will only be activated when the user clicks on a div

Comment: except this still uses setTimeout, which at this point in Browser history, you don't use for animations anymore. We moved on to requestAnimationFrame, which gives much smoother animation, with a cheaper overhead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This question was really about how to use `.setTimeout`, though. You've offered insight on rAF, but failed to address the misuse of a core function that is still worth learning, if not for animation, but for general purposes.

Comment: No, the only currently correct answer to the question of how to use setTimeout, for animation, is "don't, we upgraded JS and that function is not what you use anymore", in the same way we now tell people asking questions about document.write to not use document.write. There are still other, legitimate, uses of setTimeout for now, but this use isn't one.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. It's not just a bad use case, it was used *incorrectly*. Passing function references is a pretty fundamental concept to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). Take a look at the code below:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var line = null;

function myLine(x, y, dx, dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
}

line = new myLine(100, 5, 100, 100);

requestAnimFrame(render);

function render() {
    requestAnimFrame(render);
    if (line.y < line.dy) {
        line.y = line.y + 1;
        context.lineTo(line.dx, line.y);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.